# How to First Form Timer Start from Second form

Tags: c#

I have tried to many time to access and change property of Control like Timer
this my code please help me

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
 { 
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.timer1.Enabled = true;      
    }
}
```

and i had also tried to over loading  constructor

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }

 public partial class Form2 : Form
 { 
    Form1 mainform; 

    public Form2(Form1 mainform)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainform=mainform;
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainform.timer1.Enabled = true;           
    }
}
```

when I use constructor over loading then occurred exception error like object reference not found 
please help me ....................
thanks and regard Muhammad Azam khan

Comment: When passing data between forms you need to use the same instance of the form that exists (not create a new instance).  See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: if you want to access different form, you'll have to somehow pass a reference to that form, not create a new object (first approach) assume that this reference will be passed in a constructor on its own. When creating Form2 (don't know how you do that) simply pass the current form (I'm assuming that you create Form2 somehow from Form1)

Answer (score 1):

in Form1:

```
 public bool TimerEnable{
      get{ return  timer1.Enabled;}
      set{
            timer1.Enabled = value;
      }
 }
```

in Form2:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.TimerEnable = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote how to call it with the code, we could be more helpful. This exception say when you call From2 , you dont use overload constructor.

```
 public Form2(Form1 mainform)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainform=mainform;

    }
  public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
```

Maybe you farget this.If you call this

```
From2 form = Form2();
```

Mainform should be null so this exception will throw. Check your Form2 called code .